# Binding drag events to images within div - jquery

Tags: jquery, bind, drag

**I have multiple images and I want to bind draggable events to each of the image using jquery..**

```
<div class="dragdemo">
    <div id="draggableImages" class="ui-widget-content">

        <img id="img1" src="images/coffee_i_l_ny.png"/>
        <img id="img2" src="images/bird_twitter.png"/>  
        <img id="img3" src="images/safari.png"/>
        <img id="img4" src="images/traffic_cone.png"/>
        <img id="img5" src="images/skype.png"/> 
    </div>

    <div id="dropbox" class="ui-widget-header" ></div>

</div>
```

For a single image i can use this ...

```
$(#img1).draggable( {
    containment: '#dropbox',
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: 'invalid'

})
```

**But for multiple images how can i bind the drag to each image ?**
I tried below code .. but it doesnt work

```
$("#draggableImages img").bind('drag' , function() {

$(this).draggable( {

      cursor: 'move',
      revert: 'invalid'

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
 //this select all the images that are descendants of the element with id=draggableImages 
$('#draggableImages img').draggable( {
    containment: '#dropbox',
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: 'invalid'

})
```

Comment: Didn't even notice you had posted an answer. Usually I double check and run my program but this time I just scrammed!! People are just so fast here.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Nicola rightly says you could directly use dragabble on the selector:

```
$("#draggableImages img").draggable({
    containment: '#dropbox',
    cursor: 'move'
});
```

#### See working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/CX8B2/

But just to demonstrate you could also use the [JQuery.Each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method, Something like this:

```
$("#draggableImages img").each(function(i){
 $(this).draggable({ //this refers to each image
    containment: '#dropbox',
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: 'invalid'
})
});
```

`i` is a counter and `$(this)` refers to each image.

Comment: Why don't you simply select the images with the selector?I think that there is no need for .each() but maybe i'm wrong

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti you're right, updated answer. `bind()` was the first thing that came to mind as I rushed to post an answer.

Comment: Yes of course you can also use each(), but iterating on a collection is costly and so if you can you'd better avoid it.:)